# What is this clover leaf shaped metal plate I found while drilling into my drywall?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, patching-drywall, drywall-anchor

I was drilling some anchor holes for my screen mount on my drywall and ran into a strange metal plate.  It seems to be joining a piece of wood to the metal stud and butterflies out to the side and overlaps where I need to do my second anchor hole.

They seemed to have dug out some space in the drywall for it even.  It looks like it might even be partially sistering a wooden stud onto the metal stud for a short distance.

what is this thing - can I drill through it since there doesn't seem to be anything behind it.  Is it for protecting some piping or something?  I don't see anything behind it other than a piece of wood that seems a bit split.  There does seem to be black plumbing pipe to the right of it, but it's not behind the metal plate.  Is it something to fix a drywall patch since maybe they misplaced a outlet hole in the drywall initially?

I could just slide over the left 5 inches but that would mean drilling into the metal stud which I'm not sure how to do with the anchors provided (I guess I'd have to get new type of anchors?)

Should I just try to drill through that metal plate or should I try to slide over to the metal stud instead?

[image: Looking Down]

This is a photo of the plate in the cavity space, we are looking down from above inside the wall between my drywall and what I'm assuming is my brick wall (adjoining wall in a rowhouse).  To the left you can see a piece of wood slightly split and the metal stud as well to the very left of it.  To the right you can see a iron pipe that is an vent pipe for plumbing

Comment: sometimes the metal plates are used to protect the water or electricity conduits.

Comment: Protection plates are usually small, inch and a half by three or four inches.  You might have hit a construction connector or duct work.  Hard to tell from the picture.

Comment: could this be part of some plumbing fixture on the other side of the wall?

Comment: I don’t see any plumbing on that side but there is some metal clad wire and an outlet junction box on the left side of that stud.. another clue is that the drywall  underside by the metal plate looks pretty roughed up

Comment: Only though I have is providing backing support while patching plaster. But I haven't seen this particular object.

Comment: perhaps a wall plate for mounting a TV, embedded in plaster for aesthetics, by previous owners

Comment: perhaps it is for tv mounting - this spot is mid way up a wall and has junction box for an outlet as well as in wall cable outlet next to it.... though it would have been hidden and no one would have known it was there since it's covered up